# I was trying to set up drift using official documentation

Tags: database, flutter, setup-project, drift

---

`But as soon as i was using the database in main as per documentation .It's giving following errors:

`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/sqlite3-2.1.0`
`/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.g.dart:1158:5:`
`Error: Type 'ffi.Pointer' not`
`found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`ffi.Pointer<sqlite3_backup> p,`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`

`^^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/sqlite3-2.1.0`
`/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.g.dart:1172:17`
`: Error: Type 'ffi.Void' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void>`
`xEntryPoint,`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`

`^^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:13:46: Error:`
`Type 'IntPtr' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef PosixMallocNative = Pointer`
`Function(IntPtr);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:14:23: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef PosixMalloc = Pointer`
`Function(int);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:18:29: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef PosixCallocNative = Pointer`
`Function(IntPtr num, IntPtr size);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:18:46: Error:`
`Type 'IntPtr' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef PosixCallocNative = Pointer`
`Function(IntPtr num, IntPtr size);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:18:58: Error:`
`Type 'IntPtr' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef PosixCallocNative = Pointer`
`Function(IntPtr num, IntPtr size);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:19:23: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef PosixCalloc = Pointer`
`Function(int num, int size);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:23:27: Error:`
`Type 'Void' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef PosixFreeNative = Void`
`Function(Pointer);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:23:41: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef PosixFreeNative = Void`
`Function(Pointer);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:24:35: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef PosixFree = void`
`Function(Pointer);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:25:15: Error:`
`Type 'NativeFunction' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final`
`Pointer<NativeFunction<PosixFreeNat ive>> posixFreePointer =`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:25:7: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final`
`Pointer<NativeFunction<PosixFreeNat ive>> posixFreePointer =`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:29:35: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef WinCoTaskMemAllocNative =`
`Pointer Function(Size);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:29:52: Error:`
`Type 'Size' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef WinCoTaskMemAllocNative =`
`Pointer Function(Size);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:30:29: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef WinCoTaskMemAlloc = Pointer`
`Function(int);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:35:34: Error:`
`Type 'Void' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef WinCoTaskMemFreeNative =`
`Void Function(Pointer);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:35:48: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef WinCoTaskMemFreeNative =`
`Void Function(Pointer);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:36:42: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`typedef WinCoTaskMemFree = void`
`Function(Pointer);`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:37:15: Error:`
`Type 'NativeFunction' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final`
`Pointer<NativeFunction<WinCoTaskMem FreeNative>>`
`winCoTaskMemFreePointer =`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:37:7: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final`
`Pointer<NativeFunction<WinCoTaskMem FreeNative>>`
`winCoTaskMemFreePointer =`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:48:40: Error:`
`Type 'Allocator' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final class MallocAllocator`
`implements Allocator {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:60:3: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<T> allocate<T extends     NativeType>(int byteCount, {int?`
`alignment}) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:60:33: Error:`
`Type 'NativeType' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<T> allocate<T extends     NativeType>(int byteCount, {int?`
`alignment}) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:79:13: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`void free(Pointer pointer) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:115:11: Error:`
`Type 'NativeFinalizerFunction' not`
`found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<NativeFinalizerFunction>`
`get nativeFree =>`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:115:3: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<NativeFinalizerFunction>`
`get nativeFree =>`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:134:40: Error:`
`Type 'Allocator' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final class CallocAllocator`
`implements Allocator {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:138:20: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`void _fillMemory(Pointer`
`destination, int length, int`
`fill) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:147:20: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`void _zeroMemory(Pointer`
`destination, int length) =>`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:160:3: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<T> allocate<T extends     NativeType>(int byteCount, {int?`
`alignment}) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:160:33: Error:`
`Type 'NativeType' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<T> allocate<T extends     NativeType>(int byteCount, {int?`
`alignment}) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:182:13: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`void free(Pointer pointer) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:218:11: Error:`
`Type 'NativeFinalizerFunction' not`
`found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<NativeFinalizerFunction>`
`get nativeFree =>`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/allocation.dart:218:3: Error:`
`Type 'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<NativeFinalizerFunction>`
`get nativeFree =>`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:24:24: Error: Type`
`'Allocator' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`class Arena implements Allocator {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:26:9: Error: Type`
`'Allocator' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final Allocator`
`_wrappedAllocator;`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:29:22: Error: Type`
`'NativeType' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final List<Pointer<NativeType>>`
`_managedMemoryPointers = [];`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:29:14: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final List<Pointer<NativeType>>`
`_managedMemoryPointers = [];`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:40:10: Error: Type`
`'Allocator' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Arena([Allocator allocator =`
`calloc]) : _wrappedAllocator =`
`allocator;`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:50:3: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<T> allocate<T extends     NativeType>(int byteCount, {int?`
`alignment}) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:50:33: Error: Type`
`'NativeType' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<T> allocate<T extends     NativeType>(int byteCount, {int?`
`alignment}) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:101:21: Error: Type`
`'NativeType' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`void free(Pointer<NativeType>`
`pointer) {}`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:101:13: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`void free(Pointer<NativeType>`
`pointer) {}`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:120:6: Error: Type`
`'Allocator' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`[Allocator wrappedAllocator =`
`calloc]) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/arena.dart:144:6: Error: Type`
`'Allocator' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`[Allocator wrappedAllocator =`
`calloc]) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf8.dart:16:26: Error: Type`
`'Opaque' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final class Utf8 extends Opaque {}`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf8.dart:19:26: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`extension Utf8Pointer on`
`Pointer<Utf8> {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf8.dart:52:30: Error: Type`
`'Uint8' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`static int _length(Pointer<Uint8>`
`codeUnits) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf8.dart:52:22: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`static int _length(Pointer<Uint8>`
`codeUnits) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf8.dart:81:3: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<Utf8>`
`toNativeUtf8({Allocator allocator`
`= malloc}) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf8.dart:81:31: Error: Type`
`'Allocator' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<Utf8>`
`toNativeUtf8({Allocator allocator`
`= malloc}) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf16.dart:16:27: Error: Type`
`'Opaque' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`final class Utf16 extends Opaque {}`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf16.dart:19:27: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`extension Utf16Pointer on`
`Pointer<Utf16> {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf16.dart:52:46: Error: Type`
`'Uint16' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`static String`
`_toKnownLengthString(Pointer<Uint`
`16> codeUnits, int length) =>`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf16.dart:52:38: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`static String`
`_toKnownLengthString(Pointer<Uint`
`16> codeUnits, int length) =>`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf16.dart:55:48: Error: Type`
`'Uint16' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`static String`
`_toUnknownLengthString(Pointer<Ui nt16> codeUnits) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf16.dart:55:40: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`static String`
`_toUnknownLengthString(Pointer<Ui nt16> codeUnits) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf16.dart:68:30: Error: Type`
`'Uint16' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`static int`
`_length(Pointer<Uint16>`
`codeUnits) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf16.dart:68:22: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`static int`
`_length(Pointer<Uint16>`
`codeUnits) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf16.dart:93:3: Error: Type`
`'Pointer' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<Utf16>`
`toNativeUtf16({Allocator`
`allocator = malloc}) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub`
`/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.0/lib`
`/src/utf16.dart:93:33: Error: Type`
`'Allocator' not found.`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`Pointer<Utf16>`
`toNativeUtf16({Allocator`
`allocator = malloc}) {`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`^^^^^^^^^`
`Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...`
`/Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y`
`PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\office\monorepo\pa\frontend\flutter>`

please tell me how to solve it i treied flutter and flutter pub cache repair commands already